# Enums are giving me unexplained error

Tags: enums

I am having this strange error which I don't know how to resolve.  Here is my code:

```
 public static enum listType {

      OTHER("OTHER", 1,
      PROFILE("PROFILE", 2),
      PROFILE_LOCAL("PROFILE_LOCAL", 3),
      PROFILE_SHARED("PROFILE_SHARED", 4),
      PROFILE_WIDE("PROFILE_WIDE", 0);

      private String title;
      private int number;

      private listType(String title, int number) {
          this.title = title;
          this.number = number;
      }
```

Now I am getting the error between )and; at ("PROJECTOR", 0);  the error does say insert ) to complete body,  However in other enums I have it all works fine.  I can't insert ) cause it won't work.  I have tried to clean project and rebuild but still nothing, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. What language is this? 2. Where is "PROJECTOR" in your code snip? 3. Can you see what is wrong with the 3rd line, saying "OTHER"?

Comment: java, and sorry should be PROFILE_WIDE. AH I see now,  TYPO!  Sorry to bother all is working fine now. thank you for your extra pair of eyes to see my typo error.

Comment: See my full answer for a more detailed explanation of the reported error line.

Answer (score 0):

The missing `)` is reported on the line starting with `PROFILE_WIDE` because the statement ends there with a semi-colon. That is logically the last position where your list of ENUMs *could* have ended: with only one member `OTHER( ... (all other lines) .. );`

Adding a `)` at that position did not work, because at that point the syntax of the enclosing `enum` is not correct. What you got was an error reported from a preliminary syntax check -- matching parentheses inside a single ";" terminated expression --, and "fixing" it the way this syntax check suggested leads to a higher-level syntax error.

As you found, adding the `)` in the 3rd line makes everything compile correctly on both syntactic levels.